# # of times a number can be divided by 2 before reaching 1

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write code to count the number of times a whole number can be divided by 2 before reaching 1.
When I run my code it prompts me to enter a number as you'll see in my code below, but once I do so, nothing happens, just a blank line appears. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
 #include<iostream>
 Using namespace std;
 int main()
{

  float x,i=0,num=0;

     cout<<"please enter num:";
     cin>>x;
     while(x>0)
         {
             if(x/2>1)
                 num+=i;
                 i++; 
         } 

                  cout<<"Number of times "<<x<<"is divisible by 2 is:"<<num<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Your loop depends on the value of `x`. Where are you modifying the value of `x`?

Comment: You just want the number n, where x <= 2^n (use mathematics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are twp problems:

1) you never update x, so you'll iterate a long time.

2) x/2>1 even if x is not divisible by two.  Consider use of modulo for the test

For example:

```
 ...
 while(x>1 && fmod(x,2)==0)  // sorry %  is for integers only
 {
     num++;
     x /= 2; 
 }
```

Comment: Well, you explained it much better than I did. Removing my answer, up-voting this one

Comment: #include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{

   int x,i=1;
     cout<<"please enter num:";
     cin>>x;
         while(x/2!=1)
             {
                 x=x/2;
                 i++;
             }


    cout<<"Number of times  the number is divisible by 2 is :"<<x<<endl;

    return 0;

}


Actually w hen i use Modulo in doesnot work but when i use "/" it do work but I not getting the right answer though :( can you please check it 
The x value is even updated now :/